# sql table change sequence of items

Tags: sql, join, sequence

I have a table and I add a column (aggregate) using a field called `identidad` that is identity(1,1). I want the sequence of a group of rows.

```
       SELECT detfac.identidad, count(detfac.identidad) 
         FROM detfac  
   INNER JOIN detfac df2 
           ON detfac.identidad > df2.identidad
        WHERE detfac.nfac='000016' 
          AND df2.nfac='000016' 
        GROUP BY detfac.identidad
        ORDER BY detfac.identidad
```

it returns:

```
identidad    (No column name)
5478              1
5479              2
5481              3
5494              4
```

Everything is ok at this point.

Now I want to change a field called sequence to put the value of the second column but

```
update detfac 
  set sequence = df2.secuencia 
  from detfac df,
(
    select count(identidad) secuencia 
         from DETFAC
         where detfac.NFAC='000016' 
         and identidad<df.identidad    -- Here is the error
) df2 where nfac='000016'
```

it returns this error :

> El identificador formado por varias partes no se pudo enlazar
>
> *google translate(English)*: The identifier consists of several parts could
> not bind

So, how can I translate the select to an update?

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried using `detfac.identidad` where you get this error?

Comment: I have the error in df.identidad. It is underlined in red